# Practical use of matrix right inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times n}$ In the case when $rank(A) = n$ then this implies the existence of a left inverse: $A_l^{-1} = (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top$ such that $A_l^{-1}A = I_{n\times n}$.

Similarly if $rank(A) = m$ then this implies the existence of a right inverse: $A_r^{-1} = A^\top(A A^\top )^{-1}$ such that $A A_r^{-1} = I_{m\times m}$.

I understand how the concept of a right inverse is naturally follows in say solution of a least squares problem: $Ax = b$, $rank(A)=n<m$ has no solution because $b$ has a component in the left null space of  $A$, hence it is natural to change the problem to find the least squares solution $x_{LS}$ such that $A^\top A x_{LS} = A^\top b$ which does have a solution provided $rank(A)=n$. The solution is then $x_LS = A_l^{-1}b$. Is there an equivalent problem where the right inverse is used to solve the problem?

I expect it to involve the fact that in this case $rank(A)=m < n$ and so there are now infinitely many solutions to $Ax = b$ and that the right inverse now someone seeks the solution which minimises the length of the solution vector?

Answer (score 1):

The minimal solution to an underspecified system of equations $Ax=b$ (that is consistent) is $A^Tu$ where $u$ is any solution to $$AA^Tu=b.$$ So this is then the unique solution vector with minimal norm.

So your hunch was almost there, but the problem is we still have left matrix multiplication ($Ax=b$) and when we have to find $x$, a right inverse doesn't help much. I think its as simple as recognizing it as the transposed version of the left inverse...sometimes definitions of certain applied matrices differ in swapping rows and columns, i.e. stochastic matrices are sometimes defined as a matrix in which columns sum to 1, and others prefer to work with rows that sum to one. In the latter case it is conceivable that one would then possibly have to use the generalized right inverse if required.